# How to Import a registered Phaser3 GameObject from an external library; How to distribute Phaser3 GameObjects

Tags: javascript, shared-libraries, phaser-framework

I think my question is "How do I distribute Phaser3 GameObjects in libraries which can be reused".

Here is the issue:

Below, in `Base.js`, is a Base custom GameObject, which I want to be reusable in lots of Phaser3 games.

```
import Phaser from "phaser"

export default class Base extends Phaser.GameObjects.Graphics {
  constructor(scene, x, y) {
    super(scene, x, y)
    this.fillStyle(0x770000).fillRect(x, y, 100, 100)
  }
}

Phaser.GameObjects.GameObjectFactory.register("base", function (x, y) {
  const base = new Base(this.scene, x, y)
  this.displayList.add(base)
  return base
})
```

This is how I consume the GameObject in a scene. Vanilla stuff.

```
import Phaser from "phaser"
import Base from "@localLibrary/base/lib/Base"   // <-- This fails to fire the `register` function. 
# import Base from "./Base"  // <-- This works. 

export default class PopitScene extends  Phaser.Scene  {
  create() {
    this.add.base(200, 200)
  }
}
```

When I try to import my GameObject file from a different repo, it fails to fire the `register` function, and the error message I get is: `scene.add.base is not a function`

In this instance, I have installed the library `npm i file:../base` inside a folder called `game1`

```
project
  |- base
  |- game1
  |- game2
```

And the goal is to have different games reusing the same GameObjects inside the `base` library.

Comment: Are you sure Base is being imported at all from your scoped package?

Comment: Yes. `Base` is an object, but it's like the GameObjectFactory.register did not fire on that module.